# Add buttons to individual .obj files with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am loading number of obj files into a scene with three.js. The files come together to form one unit. My goal is to allow color customizations for each part of the rendered unit. I am trying to put buttons onto each section of the unit so that when clicked I can give the user the different customization options for the section of the unit. I am not sure how to approach this. I have everything loading up just fine but am having trouble figuring out how to add child objects to the different components of the unit. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I display tag on an object when the mouse over the object by using raycaster

```
 //Create a vector to project mouse on objects
 var vector = new THREE.Vector3(mouseX, mouseY, 1);
 projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);

 raycaster.set(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());
 // Find intersected object
 var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);

 if (intersects.length > 0) {
    var intersected = intersects[0].object;
    // drawtag is a method defined on the object to draw the additionnal elements (shape, text...)
    intersected.drawTag();
 }
```